# Is there a way to repaint the screen or navigate to a different screen on AppLifecycleState.paused in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app that contains sensitive medial information and business wants this information to be hidden when the app is put into the background, including the Recent Apps screen.

I have added WidgetsBindingObserver and am listening to the events correctly.  Resumed state correctly fires and sends user back to login page; however, the paused event doesn't do anything on receipt of the state.  For reference I have tried pushing a new screen onto the stack as well as popping all screens until reaching the login but neither works.

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => new Splash(
                inBackground: true,
              ),
        ));
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/login');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

I expect that when the paused event is received to be able to change the screen to protect this sensitive info.  Any ideas are welcome!

EDIT: Most recent code.

```
import 'package:boxview_mobile_flutter/screens/splash/index.dart';
import 'package:boxview_mobile_flutter/services/shared_prefs.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PushNotifications extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PushNotificationsState createState() => _PushNotificationsState();
}

class _PushNotificationsState extends State<PushNotifications> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool loggedOut = false;
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Splash(loggedOut: this.loggedOut));
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print("Paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print("inactive");
        setState(() {
          loggedOut = true;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        print("suspending");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        setState(() {
          loggedOut = false;
        });
        print("resumed");
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      SharedPreferencesHelper.setFirebaseToken(token);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Splash is just a splash page and the boolean loggedOut param just says don't forward to login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont forget to add `with WidgetsBindingObserver` to your state class

`class YourClass extends StatefulWidget { ....`

`class _YourClassState extends State<BottomNavigator> with WidgetsBindingObserver { ...`

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  AppLifecycleState _notification;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print("Paused");
        setState(() {
          _notification = state;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        setState(() {
          _notification = state;
        });
        print("inactive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        setState(() {
          _notification = state;
        });
        print("suspending");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        setState(() {
          _notification = state;
        });
        print("resumed");
        break;
    }
  }
```

and change your app state with `_notification`

for example

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _notification == AppLifecycleState.inactive
        ? Scaffold(
            body: Text("inactive"),
          )
        : YourRealWidget()
```

[image]

you can look more infromation for [WidgetsBindingObserver from here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)

Comment: Is there not a way to do this globally?  I'd hate to have to implement this in every screen.

Comment: You can implement that code in your root , so this will work in your every tab, it can be `CupertinoTabBar` `BottomNavigationBar` or `TabBar` if you'r using any,

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This does not work for me if I put it in my root widget.